# How do we share data between two different services

Tags: sharing

I am currently working on a web service which is periodically polled. It does not store its state and is instantiated everytime it is queried. Essentially, it retrieves the state of other external entities e.g. databases and delivers it back to the requester.

Recently, the need to store state as arisen in that

- There is the need to continously collect data from a particular source and store the bits that are important/relevant
- There is the need to collect the aggregate of a particular data source over a period of time

I came up with the following idea:
[image]

My main concern here is the fact that I am using a static class (essentially a global) to share data between the two services. Is there a better way to doing this?

**edit:** Thanks for the responses thus far. Apologies for the vaguesness of this question: just trying to work out what is the best way to share data across different services and am unsure as to the specifics (i.e. what is required). The platform that I am developing on is the .NET framework and both services are simply WCF services hosted as a Windows service.

The database route sounds like the most conventional way to go - however I am reluctant to go down that path for now (mainly for deployment/setup issues; it introduces the need to create new tables, etc in addition to simply installing the software) for at this point the transfer of relatively small amounts of data. This may of course change in the future and going the database route might be the way to go at that point.

Is there any other way besides adding a database persistance layer?

Comment: Are you using any specific language or framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to collect and aggregate data, you might want to consider using a database between the two layers. Or have I misunderstood something?

You should consider enhancing your question with more requirements: pretty much all options are open here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - how about data binding? I don't have a lot of information to go on here - about your platform but most sufficiently advanced systems offer it in some form.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your static shared data with some database representation, with a caching layer (like memcached) between the database and the webservice, so that most of the time the data is available very quickly from the cache, but can be retrieved from the database as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that you want to keep the architecture simple. Depending on the magnitude of items you have to look up and there permanency, you might just consider leveraging your file system or a message queue. It sounds like you want a file system, because that sounds the least amount of impact to your design.

If you start dealing with tens of thousands of small files, your directories could get hard to navigate and slow to do file lookups on. I typically shoot for about 1000 - 10000 files per directory, and concoct a routine that can generate a path to the file depending on the file name pattern. Keeping the number of subdirectories even is important, some file systems have a [limit on the number of subdirectories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#cite_ref-0) in a parent directory.